# Find number of items per row in Google-like thumbnail preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

I'm making a thumbnail grid with expanding preview like 'Google Images'. The idea is to get  clicked item index, clicked item row number and the item after which the expanding container will be inserted.

The problem is that when i click any item for the first time everything goes as expected but when i click the same element again the previous values doubled, the same thing happens when re-sizing the container repeat toggling up and down.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5H3vA/)**

And Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <div id="project-wrapper"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;  
}


    ul {
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 0;
    }

    .container {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }



    ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-size: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) { ul li { width: 33.333333333333%; } }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { ul li { width: 50%; } }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { ul li { width: 100%; } }

    ul li + li { border-left: 1px solid #000; } 

    ul li a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #999;
    }

    ul li div {
        position: absolute;
        top: auto;
        left: 0;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #666;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #project-wrapper {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        display: none;
    }
```

**JS**

```
var list       = $('ul'),
    listItems  = $('ul li'),
    projectWrapper = $('#project-wrapper');

    totalItems = $('ul li').length;


var gridInfo = function (){

    var itemsPerRow  = 0,
        rowsNumber   = 0,
        lastRowItems = 0;

    listItems.each(function(){
        var $self = $(this);

        if ($self.prev('li').length > 0) {
            if($self.position().top != $self.prev('li').position().top) return false;
            itemsPerRow++;
        } else {
            itemsPerRow++;
        }
    })

    lastRowItems = totalItems % itemsPerRow;
    rowsNumber   = ( lastRowItems != 0 ) ? ( (totalItems - lastRowItems) / itemsPerRow ) + 1 : ( (totalItems - lastRowItems) / itemsPerRow) ;

    return {
        itemsPerRow  : itemsPerRow,
        rowsNumber   : rowsNumber
    }
}


$(window).on("debouncedresize", function( event ) {

    if (listItems.hasClass('active')) {
        var activeItem = $('li.active'),
            currentItemIndex = listItems.index( activeItem ) + 1,
            targetRow = Math.ceil( currentItemIndex / gridInfo().itemsPerRow ),
            targetItem = ( targetRow != gridInfo().rowsNumber  ) ? ( targetRow * gridInfo().itemsPerRow ) -1 : listItems.index(listItems.last());

        projectWrapper.insertAfter( list.find('li:eq(' + targetItem + ')') );
    }

});

listItems.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var $self = $(this);
    listItems.removeClass('active');
    $self.addClass('active');

    var currentItemIndex = listItems.index($self) + 1,
        targetRow = Math.ceil( currentItemIndex / gridInfo().itemsPerRow ),
        targetItem = ( targetRow != gridInfo().rowsNumber  ) ? ( targetRow * gridInfo().itemsPerRow ) -1 : listItems.index(listItems.last());

        projectWrapper.show().insertAfter( list.find('li:eq(' + targetItem + ')') );
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reposition your projectWrapper on each click. May be move it to last position and then try to place it at its computed location.

Also in your click event call gridInfo once and store value in some variable instead of making 4 separate calls.

Comment: my problem is with variables values they are not as i expected they are doubled. besides your answer didn't solve the problem when resizing while the preview container is opened.

Comment: After placing the projectWrapper, when script try to evaluate following code ($self.prev('li').length > 0) .. for li immediately after projectWrapper. It results in length=0 which increment the value of itemsPerRow

Comment: @MoAli Do the same thing in resize function. Add the following line: projectWrapper.hide().insertAfter(list); at the start of function.